# Creating class objects in a function and retaining them

Tags: python, pygame

I'm building a game in Python with Pygame. I have created a class that acts as a button. When clicked it cycles through various states (it'll do more later.)

What I need is a grid of them that I can adjust the size of dynamically. I have a function that iterates and assigns the class objects coordinates and makes the grid (the images spawn but end up being static), but I'm not sure it's creating the objects correctly. Even if it does, they get dropped from memory when the function ends since they're local.

I've looked at a lot of stuff and people say to use dictionaries to store dynamically created objects, but I need the class objects to still be able to use their functions. Is there a way to iterate a group of class objects with dynamic names and retain them? I can manually make a huge grid of them, but I'd really rather not have to explicitly create and assign 100 or more coordinates to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary (or list, or whatever) *is* the answer. I don't understand why you would think that storing instances in a container would mean you can't access their methods. You can, in exactly the same way as before.

For example, if your class has a method "my_method" you can call it on an object of that class retrieved from a dictionary:

```
my_dict['my_instance'].my_method()
```

Comment: Excellent. I didn't realize that dictionaries stored the entire object and kept it usable. Thought it was just a collection of data. I suppose that would make it a list =P. Anyway. Got it working. Thanks a ton!